# Procedure or function 'InsertaUsuario' expects parameter '@nombre', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

tengo un error a la hora de llamar mis procedimientos en vs, estoy tratando de insertar usuarios.
Mis procedimientos son los siguientes:
Aquí tengo el nombre, tipo de usuarios y ID

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertaUsuario](
@id int = 0,
@nombre nvarchar(50),
@memo nvarchar (50)
)
AS
BEGIN
Set NOCOUNT ON

MERGE [Vendedores] as TARGET
USING (SELECT @id, @nombre, @memo) AS SOURCE(SlpCode, SlpName, Memo)
ON TARGET.SlpCode = SOURCE.SlpCode
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @nombre = SOURCE.SlpName,
               @memo = SOURCE.Memo
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (SlpCode, SlpName, Memo) values (@id, @nombre, @memo);
END
```

Y para Contraseñas uso el siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usuario](
@id2 int = 0,
@pass nvarchar (50)
)
AS
BEGIN
Set NOCOUNT ON

MERGE [Usuarios] as TARGET
USING (SELECT @id2, @pass) AS SOURCE(SlpCode, passw)
ON (TARGET.SlpCode = SOURCE.SlpCode)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET  @pass = SOURCE.passw
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (SlpCode, passw) values (@id2, @pass);
```

END

Y en VS lo tengo así:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Slpcode = 0;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtID.Text))
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(TxtID.Text, out Slpcode))
        {
            lblMensaje.Text = ("El ID debe ser un valor numérico");
            return;
        }
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("InsertaUsuario", cn))
            {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            OdbcParameter pam = new OdbcParameter("id", OdbcType.Int);
            pam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TxtID.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", TxtNombre.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memo", List.SelectedItem.ToString());
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (OdbcCommand cnn = new OdbcCommand("Usuario", cn))
                {
                    cnn.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    OdbcParameter pa = new OdbcParameter("id2", OdbcType.Int);
                    pam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pa);
                    cnn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(TxtID.Text));
                    cnn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TxtContra.Text);
                    int dv = cnn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rows == 1)
                {
                    if (dv == 1)
                    {
                        lblMensaje.Text = "Datos añadidos correctamente";
                        Grilla.DataBind();
                        Limpiar();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMensaje.Text = "Error al ingresar datos";
                    Limpiar();
                    return;
                }
                }
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ese parametro de salida esta bien? fijate el orden en que ingresas los parametros.

Comment: Al ejecutar los procedimientos en sql si funcionan bien e ingresan los datos correctos, pero cuando ejecuto en vs al momento de dar ingresar me sale el error. Mando a llamar los parámetros de acuerdo a cómo se muestran en la Grilla.

Comment: Si sacas OdbcParameter pam = new OdbcParameter("id", OdbcType.Int); del codigo (y las otras lineas de ese parametro) te empieza a decir que falta el id no?

Comment: Si los elimino, el error sigue: System.InvalidCastException: El objeto debe implementar IConvertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hola creo que tu problema es la forma en que declaras los parametros

si usas `@parametro` visual studio lo interpreta como si fuera un parametro usando `System.Data.SqlClient` sin embargo en tu codigo se ve que usas `ODBC`

la forma correcta de declarar los paramatros deberia ser:

Ej:

```
Select columna FROM tabla WHERE parametro = ?
```

El signo ? representaria tu parametro y en el ejemplo que te doi corresponde al parametro con ID 1

asi, cuando lo declares en tu codigo:

```
OdbcCommand.Parameters.Add("1", data);
```

si hay mas parametros se definen de acuerdo al orden que tienes en tu consulta sql, de forma correlativa (1, 2, 3, etc.)

para mayor informacion puedes ver este enlace:
[asignar parametros a consultas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms140355(v=sql.120).aspx)

saludos.

Para un procedimiento almacenado:

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call MiProcedimiento(?)}", OdbcConnection);
cmd.parameters.add("@parameter", OdbcType.Char, 5);
cmd.Value = "TuValor";
```

Edito:

segun tu codigo el procedimiento "InsertaUsuario()" recibe tres parametros y no uno, por lo que deberias modificar `{call InsertarUsuario(?)}` por

```
{call InsertarUsuario(?, ?, ?)}
```

y pasar los tres parametros con los nombres que definiste en tu procedimiento, lo mismo para el prcedimiento Usuario que recibe dos parametros por lo que deberia ser:

```
{call Usuario(?, ?)}
```

para los parametros podrias dejarlo asi (Usuario)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@id2", "tu dato"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@pass", "tu dato"));
```

InsertarUsuario

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@id", "tu dato"));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@nombre", "tu dato"));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@memo", "tu dato"));
```

verifica que los tipos de dato coinciden con los tipo de datos que defines en tu procedimiento almacenado.

por ultimo creo que estas lineas estan mal definidas o simplmente no deberían ir:

```
OdbcParameter pam = new OdbcParameter("id", OdbcType.Int);
pam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pam);
```

lo mismo con esta:

```
OdbcParameter pa = new OdbcParameter("id2", OdbcType.Int);
pam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pa);
```

prueba eliminando esa linea y solo deja los parametros que corresponden a los parametros que definiste en tus procedimientos.

El error `System.InvalidCastException` puede ser porque estas tratanto de convertir tipos de datos distinto, por eso verifica que los datos que estas enviando en tu codigo sean los correcto y que tampoco esten nulos.

Comment: Hola, primero que nada gracias por responder! Eh hecho como me has dicho pero me arrojó otro error: System.InvalidCastException: El objeto debe implementar IConvertible.

Comment: Hola si pudieras mostrar el codigo modificado, tal vez te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: edité la respuesta, prueba con esos cambios a ver si ahora funciona.

Comment: Entonces tendría que usar la sintaxis  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@id", OdbcType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TxtID.Text); para cada parametro?

Comment: no, solo debes usar  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@id", "tu valor")). de esa forma automaticamente estas definiendo el tipo de dato, su valor y ademas agregando el parametro a tu cmd.

Comment: si a tu parametro le agregas un 10 por ejemplo (en el caso del ID) asume que el tipo de dato es int. obviamente debes convertir el dato al tipo de dato que tiene tu parametro. como bien dices tu usa Convert.ToInt32(TxtID.Text)

Comment: Gracias, gracias! Ya me funcionó!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente modifique las líneas de instrucción para validar los parámetros.

```
 cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call InsertaUsuario(?)}", cn))
            {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            OdbcParameter pam = new OdbcParameter("id", OdbcType.Int);
            pam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pam);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OdbcType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TxtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OdbcType.NVarChar,50).Value = TxtNombre;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OdbcType.NVarChar,50).Value= List.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (OdbcCommand cnn = new OdbcCommand("{call Usuario(?)}", cn))
                {
                    cnn.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    OdbcParameter pa = new OdbcParameter("id2", OdbcType.Int);
                    pam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pa);
                    cnn.Parameters.Add("1", OdbcType.Int).Value =  Convert.ToInt32(TxtID.Text);
                    cnn.Parameters.Add("2", OdbcType.NVarChar,50).Value= TxtContra.Text;
                    int dv = cnn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rows == 1)
                {
                    if (dv == 1)
                    {
                        lblMensaje.Text = "Datos añadidos correctamente";
                        Grilla.DataBind();
                        Limpiar();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMensaje.Text = "Error al ingresar datos";
                    Limpiar();
                    return;
                }
                }
            }
```